# Wordpress - Allow Editors To Manage Theme Widgets

Tags: wordpress, editor, widget

Is it possible to grant Editors the ability to manage theme widgets? By default, only Administrators can do so.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you're going to need to use a plugin to achieve this, since changing Widgets is a [switch_themes capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) not available to Editors. You need a plugin that changes roles and capabilities (like [Capability Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/)). Check a [similiar topic about this issue in Wordpress Forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/237804).

Comment: Capability Manager looks out of date. I used "Members" module to achieve it.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to use a plugin, you can also add this to your functions.php or somewhere similar.

```
$role = get_role('editor');
$role->add_cap('edit_theme_options');
```

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress 3.2.1 the capability is `edit_theme_options`. `switch_themes` will do nothing more than allow you to activate a different theme from the available ones.

Comment: edit_theme_options works fine for me. Only one problem, now the editor could see too much menu options, as "Themes", "Menus" etc.

Comment: Yeah, it's the case that widgets are bundled with the other stuff as theme options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are several ways to this. If you don't want to mess with the code you can use a plugin called admin menu editor which will give Editor role access to the widgets and theme options. The unfortunate part for me is the wp bundled up access to widgets with access to theme options. To solve this you install another plugin called Adminize which will give you options to hide stuff from the menu.

The second solution is to use the code in the functions.php

```
$role = get_role('editor');
$role->add_cap('edit_theme_options');
```

and then install Adminize to hide stuff like theme-options if you only want to create widget access for your admin.